# Suggest me better ways to handle with the below snippet

Tags: javascript

I coded for new window open logic something like below:

```
if(condition){
    //some logic
}else {
 window.parent.location = '/klop/uiop/ddr/cart.jsp?ccode='+ccode;
}
```

Whereas, It's working as expected. but the problem is, it's failing while doing the fortify scan and it's raising a warning with

> "redirect vulnerabilities occur when a web application redirects"

Can you please help me, in how to resolve this.

Comment: Can `ccode` be generated from user input?

Comment: Well, it's in the URL so anyone could edit it if they wanted to. I think he just needs the sanitize `ccode` if he retrieves it from another page...

Comment: @Creator, I don't really know anything about the JSP syntax but, have you considered POST-ing the ccode?

Comment: @Alex, thanks for reply...ccode is a number it's there in switch case. the value is not an input from user..

Comment: @Jacob, Thanks for reply, as it;s an existing functionality..now it's very hard to change the request type...That too...that service code base is not in our end

Comment: @Creator Then as I stated above, I think the only way to protect that value is to sanitize it once you retrieve it from another page since you can't prevent the user from changing the URL.